# Endpoints Authorization with GAE on Android. User=null

Tags: android, google-app-engine, endpoints

I'm developing an android application that uses GAE and I'm trying to make authenticated calls. I have a problem making everything work. When I checked the first parameter in authorized function (User) it's always null. 
Here is my android code:

```
settings = getSharedPreferences("TicTacToeSample", 0);
    credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingAudience(this,
            "server:client_id:504148155997.apps.googleusercontent.com");
    credential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);

    if (credential.getSelectedAccountName() == null) {
        startActivityForResult(credential.newChooseAccountIntent(), 2);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                credential.getSelectedAccountName(), 10000).show();

        MessageEndpoint.Builder endpointBuilder = new MessageEndpoint.Builder(
                AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new GsonFactory(),
                credential);

        messageEndpoint = CloudEndpointUtils.updateBuilder(endpointBuilder)
                .build();
    }


private void setAccountName(String accountName) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putString("pref", accountName);
        editor.commit();
        credential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);
        this.accountName = accountName;
    }

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
    case 2:
        if (data != null && data.getExtras() != null) {
            String accountName = data.getExtras().getString(
                    AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
            if (accountName != null) {
                setAccountName(accountName);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                editor.putString("pref", accountName);
                editor.commit();
                // User is authorized.
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        credential.getSelectedAccountName(), 10000).show();
                credential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);
                MessageEndpoint.Builder endpointBuilder = new MessageEndpoint.Builder(
                        AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                        new GsonFactory(), credential);

                messageEndpoint = CloudEndpointUtils.updateBuilder(
                        endpointBuilder).build();
            }
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

And here is my GAE:

```
    @Api(name = "deviceinfoendpoint", clientIds = { Ids.WEB_CLIENT_ID,
        Ids.ANDROID_CLIENT_ID }, audiences = { Ids.ANDROID_AUDIENCE }, namespace = @ApiNamespace(ownerDomain = "safeandroid.com", ownerName = "safeandroid.com", packagePath = "mjmobilesolutions"))
public class DeviceInfoEndpoint {
...

@ApiMethod(name = "insertDeviceInfo")
    public DeviceInfo insertDeviceInfo(User user, DeviceInfo deviceinfo)
            throws OAuthRequestException {
        EntityManager mgr = getEntityManager();
        if (user != null)
            deviceinfo.setUser(user);
        else
            throw new OAuthRequestException("Not authorized!");
        try {
            if (containsDeviceInfo(deviceinfo)) {
                throw new EntityExistsException("Object already exists");
            }

            mgr.persist(deviceinfo);
        } finally {
            mgr.close();
        }
        return deviceinfo;
    }
}
```

When I'm running my app I always get the following exception from the `insertDeviceInfo` function:

```
    09-26 15:55:18.185: E/com.safeandroid.mjmobilesolutions.GCMIntentService(3833): Exception received when attempting to register with server at https://velvety-347.appspot.com/_ah/api/
09-26 15:55:18.185: E/com.safeandroid.mjmobilesolutions.GCMIntentService(3833): com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 401 Unauthorized
..
09-26 15:55:18.185: E/com.safeandroid.mjmobilesolutions.GCMIntentService(3833):     "message" : "com.google.appengine.api.oauth.OAuthRequestException: Not authorized!",
```

I tried putting the `web_id` and `android_id` in credentials, but it didn't work. What's wrong?

Comment: I am struggling with exactly the same thing. It works from Javascript but not Android. Did you find a solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

In the Android code, as audience, try to put the "Client ID for web application" that you can find in the UI.

```
credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingAudience(this,
        "server:client_id:putHereTheClientIDForWebApplication");
```

This has worked for me,
the other things seems correct